# How to route lan traffic from one NIC to vpn connection that uses another NIC

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2008-r2, routing

I have a server (windows server 2008 r2) with two nics. One is connected to a local lan, the other to the internet. It has a vpn connection setup to connect across the internet to another server to access a remote lan. How can I configure the local server so that the local lan can connect to the remote lan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to set up site-to-site routing via "Routing and Remote Access" (RRAS).